# How Do You Calculate Probabilities of Random Events Occuring in Sequence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, markov-chains, random-walk

So I have a series:

$f(x_{n+1})=x_n \pm t$

and

$f(x_0)=W$

What I'd like to calculate is the probability in terms of $t$ and $W$ (assuming they're any constant $W>t$) that any $f(x_q)=0$ for all $q$ from $[0,n]$ assuming that $t$ is either randomly added or subtracted with $50/50$ probability in each iteration.

Specifically, I'd like to know not just the equation, but how you get to it.

I feel like it should be

$P=\frac{t}{2^nW}$

but it's more just an intuition in that I know the probability should go down if $\frac{W}{t}$ goes up because you'd need more trades, but it falls apart in the example where $W=100$ and $t=1$ and $P\neq 0$ for $n=1$

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: You can just ask [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F49)

Comment: I've hit a [problem](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sigma+from+n%3D1+to+2500+1%2F%282%5En%29*nCr%28n%2C%28100%2Bn%29%2F2%29) where the binomial coefficicent is giving me a probability greater than 1... seems off

Answer (score 1):

You can transform it by dividing by $t$, so $f(x_{n+1})=f(x)\pm 1$ and $f(x_0)=\frac Wt=w$  Clearly if $w$ is not an integer, you will never have $f(x)=0$  Even more, if $w$ is odd, you must take an odd number of steps, while if $w$ is even, you must take an even number of steps.  If you want $f(x_n)=0$, you must have $w$ more negative steps than positive ones, so must have $\frac 12(w+n)$ negative ones and $\frac 12(n-w)$ positive ones.  Now look up the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to find the chance you get $\frac 12(w+n)$ heads out of $n$ coin tosses.

Comment: The Probability Mass Function or Cumulative Distribution?

Comment: The pmf gives the chance you have exactly zero.  The cmf (if you get the polarity right) give the chance you have less than zero (maybe equal)

Comment: I'm looking for the chance that it will ever reach zero, not necessarily that the value will be zero at n... let me rephrase question.

Comment: Then look up the [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk).  You will reach zero with probability $1$, but that doesn't mean that all paths reach zero.

Comment: I know it's a Markov Chain... could I maybe do a Sigma of the binomial pmf for all $q$ from $[0,n]$

Comment: That is exactly the definition of the cmf.

Comment: We're on the right track, but the CMF doesn't tell me the probability will reach zero, merely the probability we'll have $k$ successes. To reach zero I'd need $k+\frac{(n-k)}{2}$ successes... trying to refigure with that... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE:

The correct equation appears to be:

$$
P = 1- \prod\limits_{n=1}^{q} {\left(1-\dbinom{n}{\frac{W+tn}{2t}}\frac{(n+1)\bmod 2}{2^n}\right)} 
$$

Everything below was inaccurate because I forgot you can't add probabilities without eventually going over one.

**This was all wrong:** 
It appears the equation I was looking for is a modified form of the binomial distribution such that

$$
P = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{q} {\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 \dbinom{n}{\frac{\frac{W}{t}+n}{2}}\frac{1}{2^n} &\mbox{ if $n$ is even} \\
  0 &\mbox{ if $n$ is odd}
       \end{array} \right.}
$$

Which can be simplified to
$$
P = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{q} {\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 \dbinom{n}{\frac{W+tn}{2t}}\frac{1}{2^n} &\mbox{ if $n$ is even} \\
  0 &\mbox{ if $n$ is odd}
       \end{array} \right.}
$$

This gives me zero for all $n$ such that $n<\frac{W}{t}$ because for all $n\frac{W}{t}$ I'd be trying to choose more elements than the set contains in the combination operation, and if we are randomly adding or subtracting $t$, an odd number of iterations such that $n> \frac{W}{t}$ we cannot reach zero because there must be more additions of $t$ than subtractions (or vice versa) in excess of the intial $\frac{W}{t}$.

Further, I can bring it to the form:
$$
P = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\lfloor {\frac{q}{2}} \rfloor} {\dbinom{2n-1}{\frac{W+2tn-t}{2t}}\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}}
$$

to eliminate the even/odd branching. I think.

Thanks to Ross Millikan for pointing me in the right direction.

The only problem I have left is that the components become incomputably large and small respectively rather quickly ($q \approx 1035$ in Excel or Desmos) despite the probability growing with $q$.

Note: I'm posting this for peer review, not because I'm sure it's right.

Comment: Should be a product function not a sum. Will update answer.